# this program rotates a 2d array 90 degrees to the right - can i apply the values of the old array into a new array according to [col] and [row] index?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to take the values in 2d array 'arr' and place them in a different order in 'arrRotated' using for loop differentiating column and row indexes each iteration.

I tried this:

```
for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int count = 0; count <= 6; count++)
    {
        arrRotated[count][i] = arr[i][count];
    }
```

But I get an error:

> expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

This is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DisplayArray2D(char arr[][7]);
void RotateArray2D(char arr[][], char arrRotated[][]);

int main()
{
    char arrRotated[7][7];
    char arr[7][7] = 
{
{ '*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
{ '*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
{ '*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' '},
{ '*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
{ '*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' '},
{ '*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
{ '*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
};

    RotateArray2D(arrRotated, arr);
    DisplayArray2D(arrRotated[7][7]);
}

void DisplayArray2D(char arr[][7])
{
    int i, count;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (count = 0; count < 7; count++)
            printf("%c", arr[i][count]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void RotateArray2D(char arr[][], char arrRotated[][])
{
    for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count <= 6; count++)
        {
            arrRotated[count][i] = arr[i][count];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot have `[][]` in parameter.  Try `void RotateArray2D(size_t row, size_t col, const char arr[row][col], char arrRotated[col][row])`.

Comment: The function call `DisplayArray2D(arrRotated[7][7]);` is wrong. It should be `DisplayArray2D(arrRotated);`. You should only use `[7][7]` when declaring the array.

Comment: `arrRotated[count][i] = arr[i][count];` is not a rotation. It transposes the array. It is a reflection about the diagonal.

Comment: @chux: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are an optional feature, which is not supported by all compilers (for example it is not supported by MSVC). Therefore, I am not sure if it is appropriate to recommend to someone who is not already using VLAs to use them, without pointing out that their compiler may not support them.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel VLA required in C99, optional in C11/C17.  Maybe required as parameters in C2x.  In any case, an engaged OP makes for better answers.   IAC, it was not a recommendation, but a try.  I was looking for more info to better craft an answer for OP.   Only [crickets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpGtBnVZLSk) for past 21 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `void RotateArray2D(char arr[][], char arrRotated[][])`, you must specify the size if the first dimension. You do it correctly for `DisplayArray2D`. Here's the corrected line:

```
void RotateArray2D(char arr[][7], char arrRotated[][7])
```

You are also calling `RotateArray2D` with the arguments swapped.

```c
RotateArray2D(arrRotated, arr);
```

should be

```c
RotateArray2D(arr, arrRotated);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MKv4E71z8)